# for loop for searching value in dataframe and updating values next to it

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I want python to perform updating of values next to a value found in both dataframes (somewhat similar to VLOOKUP in MS Excel). So, for

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1':['a', 'b', 'd'], 'col2': [1, 2, 4], 'col3': [2, 3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1':['a', 'f', 'c', 'd']})
In [3]: df1
Out[3]: 
        col1    col2    col3
      0  a        1       2
      1  b        2       3
      2  d        4       4

In [4]: df2
Out[4]: 
        col1    
      0  a        
      1  f        
      2  c       
      3  d
```

Outcome must be the following:

```
In [6]: df3 = *somecode*
        df3
Out[6]: 
        col1    col2    col3
      0  a        1       2
      1  f                
      2  c                
      3  d        4       4
```

The main part is that I want some sort of "for loop" to do this.

So, for instance python searches for first value in col1 in df2, finds it in df1, and updates col2 and col3 respectivly, then moves forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First for loop in pandas is best avoid if some vectorized solution exist.

I think [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join is necessary, parameter `on` should be omit if only `col1` is same in both `DataFrame`s:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1, how='left')
print (df3)
  col1  col2  col3
0    a   1.0   2.0
1    f   NaN   NaN
2    c   NaN   NaN
3    d   4.0   4.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but why is it best to avoid, and where can I read something about it? I have not found something meaningful on the internet about it.

Comment: @reebyt - loops are slow, it is main reason. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316) - `Jeff` is now one of pandas developr now.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

Simple left join will solve your problem,

```
pd.merge(df2,df1,how='left',on=['col1'])

  col1  col2  col3
0    a   1.0   2.0
1    f   NaN   NaN
2    c   NaN   NaN
3    d   4.0   4.0
```